# Spherical coordinates w.r.t. nonstandard basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra, spherical-coordinates

**Linear algebra / Matlab question**: in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, let's say that I have an orthonormal basis, $\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\}$, that is not the standard Euclidean basis vectors, ($e_{1}=(1,0,0)$, $e_{2}=(0,1,0)$, $e_{3}=(0,0,1)$). So, $v_{i}\bullet v_{j}=\delta_{ij}$, etc.

I would like to determine the orientation of these three vectors $v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}$ in the same sense that $e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}$ are oriented in the spherical coordinate system.

Let $V$ be the $3\times 3$ matrix whose columns are these orthonormal basis vectors; i.e., $V=[v_{1}\, \vert \, v_{2} \vert \,v_{3}]$.  Using Matlab (for example), I can numerically determine the coordinates of the $v_{i}$ with respect to the standard Euclidean basis. For context, I obtain $V$ by computing the singular value decomposition of a cloud of points in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ about a focal point that is located away from the origin. The columns of $V$, the singular vectors of this data array, constitute an orthonormal coordinate system that is localized at the focal point.

To do this, I begin by imposing that one of the $v_{i}$ "corresponds" to the Euclidean $y$-axis (e.g., to $e_{2}$, say).  As an example, suppose that I choose to identify $V(:,3)=v_{3}$ with $e_{2}$ (without loss of generality).  Given that the coordinates of the $v_{i}$ are fixed, having already been computed, I now want to identify/determine which of the remaining vectors $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ correspond to $e_{1}$ and $e_{3}$ (e.g., pointing in the direction of the positive $x$ and $z$ axes), respectively.

My idea is to compute the spherical coordinates of $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ relative to $v_{3}$ (the vector that has been selected to correspond to $e_{2}$).  Presuming that I do this correctly, the spherical coordinates of one of the $v_{1}$ or $v_{2}$ should equal the spherical coordinates $e_{1}$, and similarly for $e_{3}$. Again, having already decreed that one of $v_{i}$ is pointing in the direction of the $y$-axis, this will be how I identify which of the remaining $v_{j}$ ($j\neq i$) corresponds to $x$ and $z$, respectively.

Of course, if the direction in which one of the $v_{i}$ is found to be pointing corresponds to the negative $x$- or $z$-axis, then I can always multiply this vector by -1 to re-orient it correctly *a posteriori*.

In the Matlab notation for spherical coordinates $(\theta, \phi, r)$, (used here for consistency's sake), $e_{1}=(0,0,1)$, $e_{2}=(\frac{\pi}{2},0,1)$, and $e_{3}=(0, \frac{\pi}{2},1)$. See, for example:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ug/spherical-coordinates.html

Simply converting the numerical coordinates of the $v_{i}$ directly to spherical coordinates with Matlab's $\texttt{cart2sph}$ command has not worked for me.  Should there first be some sort of rotation?  Am I wrong to think that my idea will work? Please help!

Essentially, I would like to compute spherical coordinates (e.g., compute $\theta$, $\phi$, and $r$) in a non-standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

$e_2\times e_3=e_1$ and $e_2\times e_1=-e_3$. So, you could simply take the cross product of your “$y$” vector with one of the other two and compare the result to the third. If they point in the same direction, then you chose the “$z$” vector; if not, you chose the “$x$” vector.

Equivalently, toss all three into a matrix and compute its determinant. If it’s positive, then the order in which they appear in the matrix gives you a right-handed basis; if it’s negative, then the opposite order will be right-handed.

If you then want to use this as the foundation for a spherical coordinate system, the easiest thing to do, I think, is to simply convert into this coordinate system (a rotation whose matrix has the $v_i$ as *rows*, plus a translation), and then use the usual conversion formulas.

Comment: Thanks @amd, but taking the cross product results in a normal vector, and these nonstandard basis vectors, v1, v2, v3, are already orthogonal; i.e., v2 x v3 = v1, v1 x v2 = v3, etc.  I may be misunderstanding, but how does your suggestion help?

Comment: @matt1011 As far as I can gather, you’re basically trying to sort the vectors so that they form a right-handed basis. Comparing the cross product of any two of them to the remaining vector lets you do that quickly and easily.

Comment: Close (let me explain better): the vectors v1,v2,v3 already form a basis, and it would be easy to re-orient them into a right-handed basis by multiplying them by -1 as appropriate.

Here's where my question is different:

Comment: After I select one of the {v1, v2, v3} as the "y" vector, I wish to identify the "x" and "z" vectors (from the remaining v1 and v3) according to how the standard x- and z-vectors are oriented in the spherical coordinates.  In spherical coordinates, the phi and theta angles are determined in part by the angle that a vector somehow makes with the y-axis.  I want to see how the v1 and v3 vectors are oriented relative to the v2 vector, and then compare this information in spherical coordinates to see how the e1 and e3 vectors are oriented with respect to the e2 (y-axis) vector.

Comment: @matt1011 In spherical coordinates, the two angles are measured directly from the positive $z$-axis, and from the positive $x$-axis but within the $x$-$y$ plane. Once you’ve chosen one of your vectors as the unit $y$-vector, right-handedness forces the assignments of the other two to the $x$- and $z$- directions. I’ve given you two ways to work out what this assignment should be. Not sure what else you’re looking for here.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help.  Rather than sort the vectors $\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\}$ so that they form a right-hand basis, what I would like instead to do is: select one of these vectors, say $v_{2}$, and identify it as one of the standard basis vectors (e.g., $e_{2}=(0,1,0)$).  I would then like to identify which of the remaining vectors, $v_{1}$  and $v_{3}$, corresponds to $x$ and which corresponds to $z$ according to how $x$ and $z$ are oriented relative to $y$ in spherical coordinates.

Comment: @matt1011 That’s exactly the same thing.

Comment: Let me try a different route: I have $\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\}$, an orthonormal set of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ basis vectors.  Forget for a moment that this set naturally forms a right-hand basis system.  I identify one of the vectors, $v_{k}$, as the "$y$" vector (e.g., $\vec{e_{2}}=(0,1,0)$) in this set.  Doing so means that $v_{i}$ for $i\neq k$ must correspond to either the $x$ vector or the $z$ vector,  $e_{1}$ or $e_{3}$.

Comment: Which is it? Keep in mind that $\{v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}\}$ may not have originally been computed by the singular-value decomposition as a right-handed system, so $v_{1}$ (for example) may originally have been computed as pointing one way when it should be pointing in the inverse direction in order to constitute a proper right-handed system. This means that I can't simply consider the determinant of $V$ as a way to determine the orientation of $v_{i}$ ($i\neq k$) relative to $v_{k}$ because the column vectors of $V$ may already be out of order AND they may be inversely-pointing...

Comment: My idea is to use spherical coordinates to ascertain the proper identification of $v_{i}$ ($i \neq k$), given that $v_{k}$ has now been earmarked as the $y$-vector.  As an example, if the spherical coordinates of $v_{i}$ (after possibly an appropriate rotation) turn out to be $(\theta, \phi, r)=(0,\frac{\pi}{2},1)$, then I know that this $v_{i}$ vector should be identified as the $z$ vector, and thus the other $v_{i}$ can be identified as the $x$ vector $e_{1}$. I do not understand how to compute the spherical coordinates of $v_{i}$ in their basis...is there a preemptive rotation involved?